# how to fix the unsubscribe in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***TS***

```
tempThermometer = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
subscription: Subscription;

    const promises = list.map(
          (url: any) =>
            new Promise(resolve => {
              this.subscription = this.global.getData(url.link).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((res) => {
                const urlArr = new Array();
                urlArr.push(url);
                this.tempThermometer.value.filter((data: any) => {
                  if (data.spinning) {
                    return data.spinning = urlArr.findIndex((x: any) => x.sensor === data.sensor) === -1
                  }
                  return;
                });
                resolve(res);
              }, (err: Error) => {
                return reject(err);
              });
            })
        );

 merge(...observables).subscribe((results) => {
           console.log(results);
}


  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

What I want to do here is to unsubscribe the promises, because when I click to other page it still running/fetching a data and I want it to stop when I click to other page.

the unsubscribe doesn't work. how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The most basic way is to store the `Subscription` returned from a call to `subscribe`, and then calling the `unsubscribe` method on the `Subscription` when you leave the page (`ngOnDestroy` life cycle hook in Angular, more about the lifecycle hooks: [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)).

In your component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.something.subscribe( ... )
}
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

There are many other ways too:

- Using the async pipe in your template where you need the values. It will unsubscribe automatically for you!
- `take` operator that you used in your example will unsubscribe after N values.
- `takeWhile` operator that will unsubscribe based on a predicate.

Here's an article discussing 6 different ways of unsubscribing: https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f

Comment: how'bout when it use promise? or it would be like this? ``` this.subscription = this.global.getData(url.link).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((res) => {....}); ```` then in Destroy ```this.subscription.unsubscribe();```? but it doesn't work when i change to other page it still running

Comment: The take(1) operator makes the unsubscribe unnecessary (it will complete after a value has been emitted), more or less like a promise.

I recommend reading up on and experiment with promises and rxjs to get a better understanding. I would argue they're both fundamental to using Angular.